# How to eliminate black stripe on the horizon from HDRI textures?

Tags: rendering, hdri

I was wondering how can I eliminate the black stripes when I render HDRI textures. I'm new at the HDRI world.

[image]

Comment: make the ground larger and model some environment, hills, trees, buildings, etc. to create some skyline.

Answer (score 2):

If you are learning to use HDR, use a proper HDR image that is meant to be used for a 3D rendering.

You need an image that covers a range of 360 degrees preferably in equirectangular projection or Quadrilateralized spherical cube

[image]

In other words: a panoramic image that you can use as the world. Think of it as a large sphere that surrounds and lights your scene. It has to contain the information of the ground and the sky all around.

See: http://blog.gregzaal.com/tag/equirectangular/

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can use a map node with HDRIs, just as easily as image textures. Go to your world tab in your node editor, and plug it into your HDRI.